# Not able to contact Solspace support

Tags: solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

Does anyone have an idea how to contact Solspace support? The email seems to be dead for about a week now.

Comment: Worth noting it is the Thanksgiving holiday week in the U.S. so response times might be slower.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry about the trouble. We typically answer most tickets within 24 hours:

- **Freeform**: https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/support/
- **Calendar**: https://solspace.com/craft/calendar/support/

If the Support Form isn't working for you, you can always email us directly at support@solspace.com :)

Answer (score 2):

Try contacting them on the Craft CMS Slack workspace. They have an account on there, it's worked for me in the past!

Answer (score 1):

Use their support form. I quite often get a response after a day or so and they’re very helpful. Here is their Freeform plugin support form https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/support/

Comment: Using the support form I get a message back that the email adress has permanent fatal errors.